# How to remove `key` and `string` from an app config.xml to stop showing AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to set an android app project.

In their documentation it's written that:
`Simply find and edit res/values/config.xml file in the project folder. Change "banner_ad_unit_id" for Banner ads and "interstitial_add_unit_id" for Interstitial ads and you are finished. If you don't want AdMob in your app, simply remove key and string tags.`

But when I removed contents of strings or the whole string, in both case I got lots of errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-5514315741534690/1584741164</string>
    <string name="interstitial_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-5514315741534690/4538207562</string>
    <string name="ad_app_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-5514315741534690~9108007962</string>
    <string name="test_device_id" translatable="false">7170163625397D22C4A4E1FD60819BAF</string>
```

Please keep in mind that I'm really a newbie in Android Studio, so I apologize if my question is too much simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keys are "name=abc" and the value is the value inside of ">xyz<"

So just delete xyz:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false"></string>
    <string name="interstitial_ad_unit_id" translatable="false"></string>
    <string name="ad_app_id" translatable="false"></string>
    <string name="test_device_id" translatable="false"></string>
```

If you you remove the requests for an ad in your code you can also delete the entire section because the values are already empty and nothing would happen.